# JHipster app with no database

Tags: database, gradle, spring-boot, service, jhipster

[J]Hipsters!

The 5/16 section on JHipster steps is mandatorily forcing me to choose a type of database, although I'm running another mock-service project (a SpringBoot app running using gradle) to access the database because of security reasons.

So, how will be able to configure it into my new JHipster project? I understand that Liquibase will contain all the details after finishing the setup.

Can it be done when prompted during the 5/16th step or should I manually delete the entries and add this project?

Also, I'm clueless on how to add another mock-services. Any examples/samples for adding mock-services will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the JHipster microservice architecture [here](https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/) and also this [Github issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2999)(feature request).

Taken those into account and you should go with a microservice which has the ability to select:

```
➜  myapp jhipster
Running default command
Executing jhipster:app

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

                            https://jhipster.github.io

Welcome to the JHipster Generator v4.5.4
Documentation for creating an application: https://jhipster.github.io/    creating-an-app/
Application files will be generated in folder: /Users/edmond/Documents/dev/java/    myapp
? (1/16) Which *type* of application would you like to create? Microservice     application
? (2/16) What is the base name of your application? myapp
? (3/16) As you are running in a microservice architecture, on which port would     like your server to run? It should be unique to avoid port conflicts. 8081
? (4/16) What is your default Java package name? com.company
? (5/16) Do you want to use the JHipster Registry to configure, monitor and scale     your microservices and gateways? Yes
? (6/16) Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT authentication (    stateless, with a token)
? (7/16) Which *type* of database would you like to use? 
❯ No database 
  SQL (H2, MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle) 
  MongoDB 
  Cassandra
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay. It was helpful, indeed. Thanks for letting me know.